# How can I return to a production build of window 10 without losing my program

Tags: windows-10, downgrade, windows-insider

I'm currently using a insider build. Some of my program now doesn't work as expected so I want to revert back to normal build. On Microsoft website they say there are two options:

1. Wait until they release an official build and opt out
2. Reinstall from scratch

Is there any better options? I don't have a restore image, but if window can upgrade without effect installed programs then it can also downgrade that way, right? If not do we know when Microsoft will release the next official build?

EDIT: There a "Go back to earlier build" options in setting but will it go back all the way to normal build or just the nearest insiders one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Go to earlier build" recovery option will take you back to the previous build you installed on your PC, not the stable one.

You can use media creation tool to get stable release without loosing your data.

Download and run the tool and select upgrade this PC.