# How to revert to public build in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-insider

My laptop having problem with insider preview and I want to get latest public version how can I do that

Comment: See this [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/274780/how-to-switch-from-windows-10s-insider-preview-back-to-stable-without-reinstalling/).

Comment: [How to Switch From Windows 10’s Insider Preview Back to Stable (Without Reinstalling)](https://www.howtogeek.com/274780/how-to-switch-from-windows-10s-insider-preview-back-to-stable-without-reinstalling/)

Comment: The only way that doesn't require you to reinstall Windows is to go back to an earlier build.  If that earlier build is an Insider Preview build then that is what you will go back to, there is no supported way, go back to the production branch once you are in one of the Insider Preview branches.  The linked article talks about, rolling back to a previous build (which I also suggested), but it also indicates "You’ll stay on the current build of Windows 10 until a new stable build arrives, or until you opt back into Insider Previews."

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1093712/how-can-i-return-to-a-production-build-of-window-10-without-losing-my-program

Comment: @ramhound What if I stop insider preview and wait for next public build and grab that . Is that possible?

Comment: @ShantnuChaubey - That is possible.  However, you didn't ask how to do that, you asked how go back to the stable release branch after presumably already receiving more then 2 Insider Preview builds.  (If it was less then 2 then just roll back to the stable build)

Answer (score 1):

Wait for the next build announcement.

Start  button >  Settings App  > Update & security ﻿ > Windows Insider Program, and then choose Stop Insider builds.

Follow the instructions to opt out your device.

To get to a production build: you can download from MSDN or you can use the Windows Media Creation Tool which can be found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

And can be used to download Windows 10:

[image: Media creation tool]

I hope that helps!

Comment: The author doesn't want to have to reinstall Windows to get back to the production build.

Comment: The author said "My laptop having problem with insider preview and I want to get latest public version". To quote you, " 
The only way that doesn't require you to reinstall Windows is to go back to an earlier build. If that earlier build is an Insider Preview build then that is what you will go back to" But that won't be the latest public version, which is what the author does want. So he has to either reinstall or not have the latest public version. Sometimes we have to choose. Reinstalling generally isn't that big of a deal but having an unstable system is a pain. But the choice is his.